# TF-slim : FIFOQueue is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I trying to use slim to make my own dataset and to read into it.
When I tried to read into it I get the following error:

> raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue
>   '_2_parallel_read/common_queue' is closed and has insufficient
>   elements (requested 1, current size 0)     [[Node:
>   parallel_read/common_queue_Dequeue =
>   QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>      [[Node: case/If_2/DecodePng/_117 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_case/If_2/DecodePng",
>   tensor_type=DT_UINT8,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>
> Caused by op u'parallel_read/common_queue_Dequeue', defined at:
>
> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue
>   '_2_parallel_read/common_queue' is closed and has insufficient
>   elements (requested 1, current size 0)     [[Node:
>   parallel_read/common_queue_Dequeue =
>   QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>      [[Node: case/If_2/DecodePng/_117 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12_case/If_2/DecodePng",
>   tensor_type=DT_UINT8,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]

It seems that the Fifo queue is empty (not filled) as I thought...

Does some one know which part of slim is responsable to fill the FiFO ?
here is the code I trying :

```
dataset_name = 'toto'
dataset_split_name = 'train'
dataset_dir = './dataset/'
num_readers = 1
batch_size = 2
output_padding = 5
dataset_id = 3
num_max_target = 5
num_preprocessing_threads = 1
num_epochs = None

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset(dataset_name, dataset_split_name, dataset_dir, dataset_id)
    provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset, num_readers=num_readers, 
        common_queue_capacity=10*batch_size, common_queue_min=5*batch_size, num_epochs=num_epochs,shuffle=False)

    img = provider.get(['frame'])

    i = tf.train.shuffle_batch([tf.reshape(img, shape=[512, 512, 1])],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_threads=num_preprocessing_threads,
                capacity=2*batch_size,
                min_after_dequeue=batch_size)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        img = sess.run(img)
        print('ok ok')

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: I have found the probleme : it is because in my dataset I don't have only the feature 'frame'. So when I creat a dataset, then a provider, the provider wants to give me all the features into the dataset, not just a 'frame'.

Comment: and how did you solve it ? consider posting that as an answer (and accepting it )

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function for distributed training from `tf.distribute.Server()` to `tf.train.Server()` in the `train.py` file and it worked.